# Use the input value in global context in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with a small app and the front-end looks like following,

[image]

After I select the currency, the `Address Generate` button is active and with clicking it, opens a modal with input option.

[image]

I would like to have the `wallet name` in the global context. The code for the landing page is here,

```
<body id="page-top" class="index">

<!-- modal for providing the name of the wallet-->
<div id="walletNameModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">

        <!--layout of the set of modals-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--modal header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!--close the dialog-->
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Wallet Name</h4>
            </div>

            <!--modal body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--provide the wallet name as input text-->
                <input id="addressName" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <!--modal footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="addressNameSubmitBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<section id="myform">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form name="landingBox" id="walletForm" class="form-inline" novalidate>

                    <!--Select Currency-->
                    <div class="form-group controls">
                        <select id="selectCurrency" name="" title="Select Currency"
                                class="btn-primary form-control">
                            <option selected disabled>Select Currency</option>
                            <option value="0">Bitcoin</option>
                            <option value="1">Ethereum</option>
                            <option value="2">Litecoin</option>
                            <option value="3">Nem</option>
                            <option value="4">Ripple</option>
                            <option value="5">Dash</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!--Generate Address-->
                    <div class="form-group controls">
                        <button id="generateAddress" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
                            Address Generate
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!--Show Balance-->
                    <div class="form-group controls">
                        <button id="balance" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
                            Balance
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!--Show Transactions -->
                    <div class="form-group controls">
                        <button id="transactions" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
                            Transactions
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!--Send Money-->
                    <div class="form-group controls">
                        <button id="sendMoney" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
                            Transactions
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    </br>
                    </br>
                    <!--Select Address Drop-down-->
                    <div class="form-group controls">
                        <select name="" id="address" class="form-control input-sm">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


</body>
```

The project structure is following,

[image]

The JavaScript is written in the `main.js` file,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectedCurrency, walletName;

    // if the currency is selected, make the address generate button active
    $('#selectCurrency').change(function () {
        selectedCurrency = $('#selectCurrency option:selected').text();
        $('#generateAddress').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    // if the address generate btn is active and clicked, open the modal
    // to provide the wallet name
    $('#generateAddress').click(function () {
        $('#walletNameModal').modal();
    });

    // after the modal submission, get the wallet name
    $('#addressNameSubmitBtn').on('click', function () {
        walletName = $('#addressName').val();

        // prints the value 
        console.log(walletName);
    })

    // doesn't print the value 
    console.log("Wallet = " + walletName);
});
```

The `console.log(walletName);` actually prints the wallet name, but, when I go out, the `console.log("Wallet = " + walletName);` prints `Wallet = undefined`.

I think the `walletName;` is global and hence, it should also print the value then the `undefined` in the console. What's the issue here?

Update:

After putting the variable out of the scope, I still have the same issue,

```
var walletName;

$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectedCurrency;

    // some code 
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
var walletName;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedCurrency;
```